# C - What to do when double is not 8 bytes long?

Tags: c, format, standards

I have a C program and I will use it on deprecated machines. I am a little bit scared of problems with basic types compatibilities - I mean, when I ask How can I guarantee, that double will be 8 bytes long? answer is

"You can put this in your code:

```
static_assert(sizeof(double) == 8, "invalid double size");"
```

Ok, I get it...
But what do I do, when I run the code and it goes "assertion failed"?

What are my options now? How can I deal with this problem? I need to run the program on that specific machine... Is it hard to adapt the program to different size of double?
P.S. My program needs 8byte doubles

EDIT: Why do I need 8 byte doubles?
I read some data from serial port in binary format to a buffer and from that buffer I need to extract the IEEE754 double precision and single precision numbers, to do some calculations with them.

Comment: Can this even happen?  The FP instructions would fail, no?

Comment: Owait - you compile it on a deprecated compiler for the ancient machines?

Comment: This is too vague.  Why does your program need 8 byte `double`?  Why can't it use a higher precision type? Why is the program dependent on a fixed size/format?  _Much_ more is needed about how your code uses `double` to answer this.

Comment: Note that "8 bytes long" doesn't necessary mean "64 bits long". You should also check `CHAR_BIT`

Comment: 64 bit long does not mean double precision, either, let alone IEEE754 double precision. Your code require something the target computer does not provide, solution is simple: 1) fix the code to remove such requirement; 2) use a different target computer; 3) write your own `double` .

Comment: Note that `static_assert` in particular is new in C2011.  If you're targeting old machines, then you may well have to rely on old compilers that don't support it.

Comment: So your question might be "If the machine I'm using today doesn't support 8-byte IEEE doubles, how do I read my input?"  Or it might be, "If I'm content to just read doubles using my machine's native format, how can I detect at build time and fail if the machine doesn't use 8-byte IEEE?"  For the former, the answer would be "write your own code to read IEEE 8-byte doubles "by hand" (which is an interesting problem).  For the latter, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If the reason you need 8-byte doubles is because you are reading and writing them to data files that way, you need to step back and have a long, hard think about this.  Reading and writing "binary" data files is one of those things people love to do because it's "easy" and "efficient" -- but of course it's wildly unportable.  You can try to patch things up to make your binary data files vaguely portable, but it's actually pretty difficult, and by the time you do, it's no longer easy or efficient.

If you can possibly see your way clear to using text data files, just about all of your portability problems will magically vanish, and you won't have to worry about those data files any more.

You can read and write floating-point quantities to text data files using `%a`, which will do a good job of preserving accuracy and precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific types of machines and C environment on which your code must run, then you can and should study their documentation to determine whether their characteristics match your data format.  If they do, then you have no problem.  If they don't, then you have to write FP emulation code.

If you can't make this determination prior to writing the code, or if characteristics of the target machines vary in a way that makes a difference here, then you need to write the emulation code regardless.  Of course, you can use such code on any machine, so you might stop there.  You could also, however, provide an alternative code path that uses native FP, and choose between the two paths either at build time (via conditional compilation) or at run time (via an explicit test of FP representation).